# discord.js - How do I add the "TRY MY COMMANDS" feature to my bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I looked at some bot's profile and apparently, Discord added a "try out my commands" feature to bots. I tried looking everywhere and did not find anything. How do I add this feature to my bot?

(I am using discord.js v14)

Image of the try out my commands feature.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can manually add this feature to your bot's description box using the command ID.

**How to retrieve the command ID:**

1. Go to Server Settings.
2. Click on "Integrations".
3. Look for your bot and click on it.
4. Scroll up until you see the list of the commands that are deployed.
5. Right-click to copy the command ID of your choice to be displayed later.

Next, we go to **[Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)** to place the command ID into your bot's description box.

So all you need to do is to put the command that are to be displayed in this format:

```
</(command-name):(command-ID)>
```

It'll look something like this:

```
**TRY MY COMMANDS** // ** to bold the text

</play:938016496168932622> | </help:938012345242127927>
```

And here's how it will look:

[image: Screenshot showing "TRY MY COMMANDS" example. Example commands show as /play | /help]

It may not look as good as the verified version but hey, it works. You can press on it and use it like a normal slash command.

Answer (score 12):

**Global Slash Commands in Bot Profiles**

As many of you noticed, we recently began rolling out global slash commands to bot profiles last week for verified apps. This week, we're rolling them out to 100% of verified apps.

With this update, a max of 5 of your app's most-used global slash commands are now visible in your bot profile (as long as your app is verified). These commands are directly invokable, making them more discoverable and usable for users across Discord :sparklies:

**How do I enable it?**
You don't have to do anything! As long as your app is verified and has at least one global slash command, a max of 5 will be displayed in your bot profile automatically.

**Can I change which commands appear in my bot profile?**
No, at the moment you can't control which commands are present

**Credits**: Discord Developers

Comment: Do you have a link to this post?

Comment: Re *"Credits: Discord Developers"*: If it is copied from somewhere (which it seems to be, based on the writing style), at a minimum, the source must be revealed and the whole post formatted to make it clear it isn't your own words, etc. See e.g. *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't add this feature in your bot for now. It's a closed beta

Answer (score 0):

My bot received this feature today. It was added automatically (my bot is verified, by the way).